# jquery mobile $mobile.changepage method

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a html file with few pages, and when a user press a button on a specific page, I'm loading a new html file that contain pages with the results.
The page loading work just fine, the problem is that i can't manage to navigate between the new pages in the new html.
when i load the page manually on my browser, it work's perfectly.

anyone got any idea why?
i think i need to perform a kind of refresh action to the page after the loading complete, but i don't wont to do so, because the page retrieve data from a remote server, and i don't know if the refresh action will try to retrieve the data from a remote server again(and that will duplicate the time the user will wait until he get an answer).

this is the code line i use:
$.mobile.changePage( "menu.php?q="+query, { transition: "slide"} );

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`... the problem is that i can't manage to navigate between the new pages in the new html.`

This line leads me to believe that you are attempting to return a multi-page template for a remote URL link (meaning the link you press doesn't link to a pseudo-page on the same document, but rather another document all together). This is not allowed by default by jQuery Mobile (I think you can find a plugin for the functionality). jQuery Mobile only retrieves the first `data-role="page` or `data-role="dialog"` element from the returned external document.

You can either use single-page templates, where each single pseudo-page is contained in its own document and you link to each of them via a normal URL (e.g. "/contact-us/index.php")

**OR**

You can place all necessary pages in a single document, and link between them with hash based links (e.g. "#home"). When you do this, you can still retrieve data from a database, but you'll have to create the code to do so via AJAX (and most likely binding to page-events).

**OR**

Maybe there is a plugin for this. If not, it's actually not that difficult a thing to make, you just need to grab the external `data-role="page"` elements by yourself rather than letting jQuery Mobile do it, add them all to the DOM, and then transition to the first one like normal.

**UPDATE**

If you want to load multiple pseudo-pages at once, try this:

```
//hijack link clicks on links with the `click-hijack` class
$(document).on('click', '.click-hijack', function () {

    //show loader
    $.mobile.loading('show');

    //create AJAX request for pseudo-page(s)
    $.ajax({
        url      : $(this).attr('href'),
        dataType : 'html',
        success  : function (response) {

            //hide loader
            $.mobile.loading('hide');

            //get the pseudo-page(s) from the AJAX response
            var $pages = $(response).find('[data-role="page"], [data-role="dialog"]');

            //append the pseudo-page(s) to the DOM
            //(this may need to change if you are using a framework like ASP.NET as they can add wrapper DOM elements)
            $("body").append($pages);

            //now that the pesueo-page(s) is/are in the DOM, we can transition to them normally
            $.mobile.changePage('#' + $pages.eq(0).attr('id'));
        },
        error    : function () {
            //don't forget to handle errors
        }
    });

    //stop the default behavior of the link, as well as propagation of the click event
    return false;
});
```

Note: This code is untested, please take this into consideration when using the code.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, i'm loading a new file with multiple pages.

Comment: i did that because i dont know the number of pages in advance the server will bring back. it's depends on the user input.and i also want to retrieve the data from the server only once. and i didn't found a way to load multiple pages using AJAX. do you know a way to do so?

Comment: @user1528238 See the **update** to my answer. If you found my answer useful, feel free to Upvote or Accept the answer.

Comment: hi jasper i found your answer very useful.i'm new here so the only place i saw that i can accept this answer is at the bottom "was this post useful to you?", is there another place that i can vote about your answer?

Comment: @user1528238 To the left of every answer to your question you should see a hollow check-mark which you can use to *accept* an answer. While you are at it you probably should revisit your previous questions where someone solved your problem and accept their answer to. It might also be a good idea to take a look at the [FAQ on how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 0):

By default in jQuery Mobile when you link to an external page [via ajax](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html) jQuery Mobile will pull only the first `data-role="page"`, or if it can't find one it will take the contents and wrap it in a data-role="page" div.

You can link to an external multi-page document by linking to the page without ajax (add `data-ajax="false"` to your link).

If you want to load several pages at once through ajax, you can either do it yourself manually using something like @Jasper suggested or you can you the [jQuery-Mobile-Subpage-Widget](https://github.com/ToddThomson/jQuery-Mobile-Subpage-Widget) which is made specially for that purpose.

Comment: Hi, i used jasper AJAX example and it worked perfectly on my browser on my personal computer, but when i uploaded it to my phonegap application, the ajax call doesn't seems to work.In the AJAX call im calling to a php file that retrieve the data from the server with the code line "file_get_contents".and i don't have any idea why? Thank you